# Win10 cygwin find: replace slashes and enclose in quotes in xargs

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cygwin

I'm on Win10, using cygwin64 ("cfind" is cygwin's "find", I renamed to avoid confusion with Win's own "find"). In %root%, I want to delete all folders with name matching ".vs" (and their contents) using cygwin's "rm -r". I have two problems: 1) paths in "%root%" contain Win's backslashes and spaces in names. How do I pass xargs to "rm -r", so that backslashes are changed to forward slashes, and each argument is enclosed in quotes?

```
cfind %root% -name '.vs' | xargs rm -r
```

Comment: not clear why you have problem and why you are using a `%root%` variable. May be you should put an example of outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin find has its own option to remove files

```
cfind %root% -name '.vs' -delete
```

There is also an example that you can adapt to your case at
https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/
for passing file names to other programs with `xargs`

```
find %root% -name '.vs' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

but I suspect you should convert `%root%` with cygpath before using cygwin utilities.